# Why does addition give type mismatch even when I cast?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm performing operations between two blocks of data separated by a blank row, and I need to get the row of the second block. I do this by selecting the top block of data using 'Selection.End(xldown)' and then taking the row from this, and adding two to it. Since there is always a single blank row to separate the blocks, this should work, but on the line where I add two to the row, I get a type mismatch despite the fact that I'm casting the row with CInt before I add. The code in question is

```
Dim col
col = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(1)
Dim tmp as Integer
tmp = CInt(col) + 2
```

The last line of this always causes a type mismatch error. Why is that? What's wrong with the cast I'm trying? Most importantly, how do I fix it?

I couldn't find anyone encountering this problem except where they were pulling data from the sheet which seemed like a different set of circumstances.

Comment: check and see what col returns...no matter how hard you cast that, it'll never be an Int

Comment: col returns the column name. Thanks, that should be the problem then. Is there a builtin function to change the name to the number or do I just have to write one?

Comment: give my answer a whirl and see if it gets you close...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you have it set, you're returning the character representation of the address.  Try this:

```
col = Selection.Column
```

which should return the numeric position (in my limited testing it does at least)

Comment: This does it. Thanks again.